# Mcq on equality of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Which of the sets are equal

- (i) R = {x : x2 = 7}
- (ii) S = {x : x + 4 = 4}
- (iii) T = {x : x2 + 2 = 8}

(a) R and T are equal

(b) R and S are equal

(c) S and T are equal

(d) R, S and T are equal.

I think no option is correct but my teacher is saying that option a) is correct. So please clear my confusion.

Comment: Does x2 denote $x^2$?

Comment: Use x^2 to produce $x^2$ in MathJax.

Comment: You are right. No option is correct.